# I checked the <use> element and the xlink:href attribute but I couldn't find the url of an Image

Tags: html, svg

I tried inspect element to check the url(Logo-image source)

kindly access www.sfsymphony.org/index.aspx for your reference

```
<svg class="header-logo-icon header-logo-desktop"> 
 <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#sfs-logo-desktop"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reference is to another `<svg>` elsewhere in the file.

If you look at the first `<div>` in the page, you will find it there:

```
<div><svg class="svg-sprite" style="display: none;">
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            pointer-events: fill;
        }
    </style>
    <defs>
      ...
      <symbol id="sfs-logo-desktop" viewBox="0 0 262 55.2">...</symbol>
      ...
    </defs>
</svg></div>
```